# Can I access the registration tokens of all users registered in my Firebase notifications?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security, firebase-notifications

Sometimes I want to send a message through Firebase notifications to one unique user, then I want access the token from that user, so I like to know what is the best practice for get that token at any time?

On initial startup of my app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance.
I can get that token, but if I save that token in Firebase realtime database, I think other people can access that data because it is "set persistent mode on" to access offline data.

My questions is:
Is it possible to get tokens of all users without save that in a database?
Can I get these tokens direct from Firebase Authentication? If not, what is the best practice for access these tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I think other people can access that data because it is "set persistent mode on" to access offline data.*

Simply save the registration token details to a secure node. Making sure that only you (or even including the user itself) to be the only ones that can access it. Read more on [Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

> *I can get that token, but if I save that token in Firebase realtime database, I think other people can access that data because it is "set persistent mode on" to access offline data.*

Users won't be able to get the data they're not allowed to/wasn't designed to have on their device if you choose to restrict them.

> *Is it possible to get tokens of all users without save that in a database?*

There is no API to get all the registration tokens related to your app. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation) (emphasis mine):

> After you've obtained the token, **you can send it to your app server and store it using your preferred method**. See the Instance ID API reference for full detail on the API.

It's the developer's (you) responsibility to send and store the registration token to a secure location.

> *Can I get these tokens direct from Firebase Authentication?*

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this. FCM Registration tokens are different from auth tokens. So, no.

> *If not, what is the best practice for access these tokens?*

So long as you store the tokens in a secure location and make sure that you're always using the most recent/valid token, it should be good.

Comment: Thanks AL, save user data on a secure node is what i´m looking for, but the method **set persistent mode on** dont save locally these data ? someone with root access cannot access these information ? or if i configure the rules for individual user can access only they proper data, and the other users tokens will not be saved locally ?

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong where the possibility of a user's own registration token is cached on their own device. So I think this won't be an issue.